# Troubleshooting SC2262/2272 RF module interaction Arduino

Tags: arduino, rf

I'm having difficulties reading any input from my RF module to my Arduino. I hope I have done all the necessary simple tests prior to asking for help here on whether or not the receiver is faulty.

There was [a forum post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=288616.0) over at Arduino with a similar problem, but unfortunately, no solution found.

Kit:

- [SC2262 transmitter](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=426764.0;attach=182113) and [SC2272 receiver](http://www.voti.nl/docs/SC2272.pdf) 433.92 MHz with keyfob TX, cheap off eBay.
- Arduino UNO R3
- Prototyped with standard breadboard and jumper wires. D0-VT to Arduino pins 2-6 respectively.

As suggested in the other forum post, I have used a meter to measure the voltage across GND to each digital PIN and see no flicker of life with each button press. This is the M4 sub-type which I understand as momentary, however, the meter is flat 0V which I don't believe would be expected.

There is demonstrable 5V on receiver module power pins.

Using an RTL-SDR dongle also demonstrates transmission peak on button press so I don't believe the fault lies at the transmitter end. New A23 battery in keyfob.

I haven't included any code here, as I don't think this is where the fault lies. I can demonstrate correct digital reads in Serial Monitor when artificially replicating signal with 5V.

In addition, I believe that there are encoder/decoder chips onboard this module. I did try adding a library from GitHub (QuentinCG's) but it made no difference.

This leads me to believe the receiver may have a fault. However given my lack of experience, it could equally be oversight of something simple.

If you want me to put up my code, or photos of the breadboard please let me know.

[image: RF RX Module]

Address pin photos

[image: Tx Module Front]
[image: Tx Module Rear]
[image: Rx Module Rear]

Comment: Do your receiver and transmitter have the same address set?

Comment: Until you are getting outputs from the receiver, this would seem to be an off-topic question about the *usage* of *undocumented* discount gadgetry (you linked a chip data sheet, not module documentation).  Buying such is generally not recommended, unless you already have sufficiently detailed understanding of how it works to make up for the lack of support from discount vendors.  You might consider feeding the output of a bare receiver into a software based decoding library on the Arduino.

Comment: @JRE Sorry not sure exactly what you mean. Data sheet for the transmitter chip PT2264 [here](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/380/PT2264-pdf.php). There are blobs of solder on the rear of the chips. From my reading, for the rx: OSC I and TE and for tx: A9/D3 and A3. Hope that means something!

Comment: On pins 1 through 8, there are jumpers or solder blobs that set the address.  The jumpers must be set the same on the transmitter and receiver.

Comment: The 2262 and 2272 are a matched pair.  The documentation says to use a 2262 and a 2272 together.  The 2264 documentation says to use it with a 2294.  You are playing mix and match with things that don't mix.

Comment: @JRE thanks for your explanations. With a better understanding it seems that on tx: A3 is soldered to L and A6 to H. On rx: A2 and A4 are soldered to the rail above (H?). I appreciate your comment about chips, this is what was sent by the supplier. In smaller text on the tx chip it does say SCT2262 which may be relevant. Going to try to add photos of all.

Comment: @JRE whilst waiting for a new pair of modules (that will hopefully work), is it feasible to try and re-solder correct connections?

Comment: Certainly.  Make sure you have a matching pair (2272 and 2262) then check the address lines.  Use a multimeter to be sure what's high or low, and duplicate it on the address lines.

Comment: @JRE OK. I doubt my soldering will be accurate enough, however worth a stab. Have also read a little [here](http://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1473&start=20). Seems to suggest that changing the tx addresses (2262) is advised. Studying it these are currently A6 to H (appears contiguous with VCC) and A3 to L (contiguous with VSS). On rx both A2 and A4 are 'jumped' to H (contiguous VDD). So, any last piece of advice about what should go where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96419/discussion-between-jh112323-and-jre).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was verified in chat.

Problem was indeed the address settings on the 2262 and 2272.

The addess settings on both modules must be the same.

As can be seen in the following pictures, the address lines were set differently on the two modules:

[image]

[image]

The address pins are pins 1 through 8 on the 2262 and 2272, as shown in this excerpt from the [SC2272 datasheet.](http://www.sc-tech.cn/en/SC2272.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JRE. I have re-soldered the address pins on the rx module to match tx and now it works properly. Supplier reports a mix-up of batches..